# FS0001 Should be "int32", is "unit" instead

Tags: f#

First of all, I am a complete beginner to functional programming and F#. I am kinda getting into the basic concepts and I tried to start practicing my understanding by writing a Mandelbrot set program.
The function `iterate` should take a tuple, iterate over it, and in case the exit condition `infinity` is med, it should return the amount of iterations `i` it took. Else it calls itself with the changed tuple.
I receive the following error: `FS0001 Should be "int32", is "unit" instead` line 2

**Edit:**
mandelbrot takes a tuple and return a tuple;
infinity takes a tuple and return an integer

```
let rec iterate (a, b) :int32 = 
    for i:int32 in 0..100 do 
        (a, b)
        |> mandelbrot
        |> match infinity with
            | a when a > 16 -> i
            | a when a <= 16 -> iterate (a, b)
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this function due to this "mandelbrot" you defined somewhere else (or from a library I don't recognize).

Comment: The for loop is not going to work this way, as in each iteration you return an integer. The body of a for loop should return unit, hence the error. I don't understand enough what you're trying to do (Mandelbrot misses), do you expect the loop to return a single value, or a sequence?

Comment: Also, `¦> match xxx` is invalid, maybe you meant `function`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to guess what you want to achieve.  However a few tweaks could get you to compile.  A `for do` expects a function returning `unit` e.g. a statement.

If you want go through iterate up to a hundred times you could use a variable i that you pass inside the iteration and you increase it each time you make a call and initialize it with 0 e.g. `iterate (2,3) 0`

```
let mandelbrot (a,b) = (a,b)

let infinity (a,b) = a


let rec iterate (a, b) i :int = 
        (a, b)
        |> mandelbrot
        |> infinity 
        |> (fun a-> if i=100 then a else
                    match a with
                      | a when a > 16 ->  i
                      | _ ->  iterate (a,b) (i+1))
```

Comment: While not really the goal here, to make this tail recursive (100 iterations will be fine, but Mandelbrot algos can get quite deep), lose the inline function, and lose the `|>` (at least the last one). PS, +1 for the attempt, given the incomplete example in the op).

Comment: @Abel actually it's tail recursive as it is. I just checked the generated IL in release mode.

Comment: I'm surprised, as it isn't (did you see it compiled as loop, or just the `.tail` opcode? The latter is not a sign of guaranteed tail recursion). But it's true that some non tail recursive functions are nonetheless optimized that way. Don Syme however claimed that the rules are fuzzy, and that it's best to make the code purely tail recursive. In my experience, capturing the recursion inside a lambda usually doesn't get optimized, and the same is true for piping. If you're right, the optimizer has gotten better at this.

Comment: Just double checked, and you're right, it gets optimized beautifully. It may be in part because the lambda takes a single arg. Quite amazing how much the compiler "gets" here: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AbEAzAzmgExAGoAfCABxgDsACAZQE9cAXGAWwFgAodiAgK4YYtAMK0AvD1rCWtdgENqBGBmBQIcgBQK0wAJSTaOvfumzaAS2rZrllo2O6DRheZhzYYK2ygK2Tmi0Lpa0INZyErTStIHBZtyxtKQAfPJKKmoaLDHJada21PaOuanG2AJ0CrRwablJVthWEgCMAAxttCwAFjS01fVJqrgwgw2KLGDd/bQA7vbdY0mkM7O9VbRpLUg1aVZLsSsA+rux9jB+ASYuWpbELfqGQA

Answer (score -1):

Before I try to explain the function unnecessarily here is how the code would look like written in C:

int iterate(int a, int b) {
int i, ca = a, cb = b, aa, bb;

```
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    aa = a * a - b * b;     //mandelbrot algorithm
    bb = 2 * a * b;
    a = aa + ca;
    b = bb + cb;

    //checks if the the values deviate to infinity
    if ((a + b) > 16) { 
        return i;
    }
}
```

}

I thought about using recursion but since Iam not used to the functional paradigm I tried to avoid it for efficiency reason and basically tried to create a break condition. Turns out, F# compiles tail recursion into while loops so all this was just really unnecessary and dumb. https://gist.github.com/mrange/3a275cc643c9753925f1c8a68b0bd7a0

Still hope it helps someone and thanks for everyone that tried to make sense out of the code I wrote.

Comment: Welcome to SO, it's usually best to update the question (there's an Edit button), so that people understand better what you meant. Then, the person answering can update his or her answer post as well. If you do answer your own post, it's common to show the actual answer (in this case, the code you came up with), this will help others too. Glad you found a solution though.